# It is possible to create a different Publisher and Listener in the same NodeHandle?

Tags: ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

My question is in the title.

Actually, I have this :

```
subscriber = select.subscribe("select", 1, &Node::selectCallback, this);
publisher = select.advertise<std_msgs::String>("select", 1);
```

I would like the program receive vectors but publish only one string. It works for the vector but not for the string, it seems impossible to handle two differents information.

```
[ERROR] [1596527879.014894165]: Client [/select] wants topic /select to have datatype/md5sum [msg/select/6b204e294ba3cb6f15defcb9cd6b3d7c], but our version has [std_msgs/String/992ce8a1687cec8c8bd883ec73ca41d1]. Dropping connection.
```

Do I have to create a new NodeHandle or can I use only one topic for this ?

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/358623/it-is-possible-to-create-a-different-publisher-and-listener-in-the-same-nodehandle-?/) by [Pombor](https://answers.ros.org/users/56464/pombor/) on ROS Answers with karma: 5 on 2020-08-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can use a single node handle, but you must have different topic names for the publisher and subscriber. Think of you subscriber as the input to your node, and the publisher as the output of your node. Those two things must be different, otherwise you create a circular graph (first problem) with identical topic names that have different types (second problem).

---

Originally posted by [Thomas D](https://answers.ros.org/users/304/thomas-d/) with karma: 4347 on 2020-08-04

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1